# Visual Studio project error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This is my table as shown in image

[image]

This is my stored procedure for insert

[image]

but when I am trying to execute it with my project project shows error as below.

ERROR:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SID', table 'AttDemo.dbo.StdMst'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: set column SID identity on... autonumber

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this would be to set the primary key to autoincrement / as an Identity.

Alternatively, you could change This:

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STDMST_INSERT]

    @STDNAME AS NVARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO (StdMst (StdName, EDate) VALUES(@STDNAME, GETDATE())

END
GO
```

To this:

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STDMST_INSERT]

    @STDNAME AS NVARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO (StdMst (SID, StdName, EDate) VALUES(IDENT_CURRENT('StdMst'), @STDNAME, GETDATE())

END
GO
```

The issue you are having is that your primary key does not allow NULL values and is not set to autoincrement.

Here are some useful links:

[Set Primary Key as Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) 
[Setting key to autoincrement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you think that your `SID` column is an IDENTITY column, but it's not.